# Ability to control byte size of INTEGER type

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to keep an SQLite table as small as possible. My tables will only contain 1 byte unsigned integers. However, it is unclear when I create a new table what the underlying structure of the table is that gets created. For example:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (SmallNumbers INTEGER)
```

Will the resulting SmallNumbers field be 1, 2, 4...8 bytes in size?

If I were to create 1 million records all containing the number "1" using the above command to create the table, would the resulting .db file be any smaller than if I inserted 1 million records all containing the value of 412,321,294,967,295?

How do I ensure that such a table can be as small as possible as I insert 1 byte unsigned integers into the table (with regards to disk space)?

Comment: I tried creating a 1 million row database with all elements under 255 (9.5MB total size) and then creating another million row database with all elements above 65535 and the second one was significantly larger (12MB). So, it seems that `sqlite` does use an *appropriate, minimal* size.

Answer (score 7):

Per SQLite documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the
>   database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

You don't need to do anything to ensure the table will be as small as possible. SQLite will choose the smallest storage class that can store the value you supply, on a value-by-value basis.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read the URL you provide multiple times prior to posting this question.  The URL does not answer my question.

Comment: Then you may need clarify what you want to know. How does the text I quoted not answer your question? The amount of bytes used to store any integer value is just large enough to store that value.

Comment: So are you saying that the SmallNumbers field does not have a static width/size that is defined when you CREATE a new table? If so, this does not seem consistent with the SQLite feature which allows the user to set the width of a field using VARCHAR(2).  Why is VARCHAR definable with a hard size (e.g. "2") parameter limit but a field containing INTEGER values is flexible and doesn't require a size definition when the table is created?

Comment: No field in SQLite has a static width/size. SQLite allows you to type anything you want for the data type, primarily for compatibility with other SQL engines. But it only uses what you type to determine column "affinity." When you enter VARCHAR(2), SQLite sees "char" and assigns a Text affinity to that column, but the (2) isn't used for anything. You can declare VARCHAR(2) and still insert a string of 3 characters, or an integer, or anything really.

Comment: All that being said, declaring a column as INTEGER as you're doing will assign the Integer affinity, which will do exactly what you want and what was stated earlier: store any integer you insert using the least amount of bytes necessary, on a value by value basis.

Comment: So I am wasting my time creating a new table and declaring a new field with VARCHAR(2) vs. VARCHAR?  It sounds like there really isn't any strategy in keeping a SQLite at its minimum size (assuming one doesn't delete existing records).

Comment: Correct. As long your data type declaration generates an affinity that makes sense for your data, SQLite will do the best it can to store data in the smallest footprint that it can.